# Every bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove this via Liouvilles theorem but not sure how the exclusion of this point affects the conclusion of the theorem. We know nothing about the behaviour at 0 so extending it to complex plane may not necessarily work as it may not be bounded or holomorphic on at the point 0.
Can anyone shed some light on this? maybe it's not even true?

Comment: Doesn't your title's "bounded holomorphic" function contradict the text's "may not be bounded "?

Comment: but the hypothesis says nothing about the function at 0. I can see that it does not have an essential singularity at 0 as if it did any neighbourhood would contain every complex number by Casorati-Weierstrass theorem. But it could be point at infinity say or another singularity. Am I right in trying to use Liouvilles theorem?

Comment: Have you considered Riemann’s theorem on removable singularity?

Comment: I had in mind @SangchulLee's comment/suggestion... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Comment: hadn't come to mind. So since f is bounded in a region of 0 then f is holomorphically extendable over 0. Thus it is bounded and holomorphic on the entire complex plane. Then by Liouvilles theorem it is constant on $\mathbb{C}$ thus it is constant on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$. Does this work?